# Making summary of sentences

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed

I have data and I want to summarize sentences to generate conclusions. The example below is not related to the data, but just to clarify the idea so I can replicate it.

```
Employee Suzie signed one time.
Employee Dan signed one time.
Employee Jordan signed one time.
Employee Suzie signed one time.
Employee Suzie signed one time.
Employee Harold signed one time.
Employee Sebastian signed one time.
Employee Jordan signed one time.
Employee Suzie signed one time.
Employee Suzan signed one time.
```

I want to make a summary of these sentences, like this:

```
Jordan signed 2 time(s)
Dan signed 1 time(s)
Suzie signed 4 time(s)
Suzan signed 1 time(s)
Sebastian signed 1 time(s)
Harold signed 1 time(s)
```

I played with `awk`, but it seems very hard to do it. Then I tried `sed`, but it didn't work. It seems `sed` is just for finding and changing things.

Comment: Is "one" the only count possible, or can there be more events in a single line?

Comment: I thought this was [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) until I got to the last two sentences. Consider posting this there too; it would make a great code golf challenge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general approach would be

```
$ awk '{ count[$2]++ }
       END {
           for (name in count)
               printf("%s signed %d time(s)\n", name, count[name])
       }' <file
Harold signed 1 time(s)
Dan signed 1 time(s)
Sebastian signed 1 time(s)
Suzie signed 4 time(s)
Jordan signed 2 time(s)
Suzan signed 1 time(s)
```

I.e., use an associative array/hash to store the number of times that a particular name is seen.  In the `END` block, iterate over all the names and print out the summary for each.

For slightly nicer formatting, change the `%s` placeholder in the `printf()` call to something like `%-10s` to reserve 10 characters for the names (left-justified).

```
$ awk '{ count[$2]++ }
       END {
           for (name in count)
               printf("%-10s signed %d time(s)\n", name, count[name])
       }' <file
Harold     signed 1 time(s)
Dan        signed 1 time(s)
Sebastian  signed 1 time(s)
Suzie      signed 4 time(s)
Jordan     signed 2 time(s)
Suzan      signed 1 time(s)
```

More fiddling around with the output (because I'm bored):

```
$ awk '{ count[$2]++ }
       END {
           for (name in count)
               printf("%-10s signed %d time%s\n", name, count[name],
                      count[name] > 1 ? "s" : "" )
       }' <file
Harold     signed 1 time
Dan        signed 1 time
Sebastian  signed 1 time
Suzie      signed 4 times
Jordan     signed 2 times
Suzan      signed 1 time
```

Comment: why bored? Thank you very much for such great answer.... I lost any hope to do it in awk. Please is there any way to order the final result by name?

Comment: @Zolo The simplest way to sort the result by name in this case would be to pipe the output through `sort`:  `awk ... <file | sort`.

Comment: For other `awk` novices like myself, `$2` because `awk` is one of the few languages/tools that counts from 1 not 0.

Comment: @CaptainMan It's just that `$0` happens to be the whole current record.

Answer (score 8):

While `awk` is using an associated array and that would be limited to the memory size you have, you could do as the following instead:

```
sort -k2,2 infile | uniq -c
```

Or to do formatting as you want:

```
sort -k2,2 infile  |uniq -c |awk '{ print $3, "signed", $1, "time(s)" }'
```

Comment: I would cut out the name first: `cut -d " " -f 2 infile | sort | uniq -c | while read n name; echo "$name signed $n time(s)"; done`

Comment: `sort` uses temporary file(s) when the input file does not fit into the memory.

Comment: That's correct and an advantage of the `sort` command, and still that's not limited to your memory while `awk` using an array is, Also you can change the path of creating that temp files with `-T, --temporary-directory=DIR` with enough disk location you have (even `multiple options specify multiple directories`).

Comment: This is the proper unix way: use the right tools for the job (and separates nicely: the sorting, the counting, and the printing of the result)

Answer (score 3):

This job is for `awk`. You need an `array[index]` to do it:

```
awk 'NF {name[$2]++} END{for (each in name) {print each " signed " name[each] " time(s)"}}' file

Jordan signed 2 time(s)
Dan signed 1 time(s)
Suzie signed 4 time(s)
Suzan signed 1 time(s)
Sebastian signed 1 time(s)
Harold signed 1 time(s)
```

`NF` is to remove extra blank lines.
The data is stored in the index and value of the array. Values are referenced with the corresponding index.

Answer (score 0):

Without formatting, the most simple solution is

```
sort|uniq -c
```

`uniq -c` counts the lines and prefixes them with their count, sort is needed for uniq to work.

```
$ sort|uniq -c
asdf
asdf
qwer
[ctrl-d]
      2 asdf
      1 qwer
```

Your formatting could then be achieved by sed or awk, if you need that exact format:

```
awk '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c|awk '{print($2, "signed" ,$1, "time(s)")}'
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried a 'for' solution, although i am sure this can be re-edited and made dandy. Serves the purpose though.

```
for name in $(awk '{print $2}' x.txt)
do
count=$(grep -i $i x.txt|wc -l)
echo "$i signed in $count times" >>xy.txt
done

sort -u xy.txt

Dan signed in 3 times
Harold signed in 1 times
Jordan signed in 2 times
Sebastian signed in 1 times
Suzan signed in 1 times
Suzie signed in 4 times
```